# How to make faster queries on remote mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, server

I have 2 servers on OVH, they are on different datacenter in the Europe (SBG1 and GRA1). My controlled ping is 10ms.
My websites run many insert and read queries.

When I try my local mysql server it is very fast but when I use the remote mysql server the queries run is delayed.

My Remote Mysql Configuration

```
# Percona Server template configuration

[mysqld]
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
skip-name-resolve
bind-address = 5.196.77.XXX
# skip-networking
sql-mode = 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
# MyISAM #
key_buffer_size                 = 2G
# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet              = 10G
# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 32M
max_heap_table_size            = 32M
query_cache_type               = 1
query_cache_size               = 2M
query_cache_limit              = 1M
join_buffer_size               = 6M
max_connections                = 600
thread_cache_size              = 100
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 20G
innodb_data_file_path          =ibdata1:20M:autoextend

# LOGGING #
log_error                      = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
long_query_time                = 3
slow_query_log_file            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

I don't know how can i connect local connection each servers.

Do i have to use vRack? (I have but i don't know have can i use it) 
OR 
Do i have to move my servers to same location?

What should i do

Comment: Before moving your server, did you try replication ?

Comment: I never tired it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) enables data from one MySQL database server (the master)
>   to be copied to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves).
>   Replication is asynchronous by default; slaves do not need to be
>   connected permanently to receive updates from the master.

If I understood you have a server S-A width database D-A and a server B with a database D-B and a local Server S-Local with database D-Local.

You can replicate the D-A and D-B databaseson your local Server S-Local. So your query will be faster.

I'm not sure if there is communication between S-A and S-B, but you can even replicate database D-A on Server S-B and database D-B on Server S-A.

My team has to query a distant server. It is very slow. With replication, our query are connected to a local replicated server and it is very useful

Comment: Actually i have only 2 servers and i wanted to separate mysql and web applications. Because 2 servers not enough for replication. My web server load balance is 10 with mysql but if i separate it load is 3 each servers.

Comment: So It is not a non-local - distant communication problem, but a load performance problem. your problem is different. I don't know enough about OVH solution's. I'd rather use Virtual Server which I can add some CPU or Ram dynamically.

Comment: My problem is about connection. I couldn't connect as local to remote mysql server and it makes loos of performance. I need more faster connection but i don't know how can i do that. I tried to contact ovh but their support very bad :D